# What's the role of length in DatagramPacket(byte[] buf, int length)?

Tags: java, datagram

The document says`DatagramPacket(byte[] buf, int length)`
constructs a `DatagramPacket` for receiving packets of length `length`.

All examples I've seen is like:

```
byte[] data = byte[1000];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data,data.length());
```

Is there an example that we don't pass `data.length()` but something else?

Comment: It's there in case you don't want to use the whole array.

Comment: @EJP So we can have `DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data,10);` and only `data[0],...,data[9]` can be used? And for sending, `DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data,10,address,port);` does it mean we only send `data[0],...,data[9]`?